# Does Google Feed API enable access via Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, server-side, google-feed-api

I want to use Google Feed API from a server (Node.js). I have already installed the googleapis module. My code is:

```
// parts omitted
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
// parts omitted
googleapis.discover('feeds').execute(function(err, client) {
var feed = new google.feeds.Feed('http://rss.lemonde.fr/c/205/f/3050/index.rss');
});
// parts omitted
```

But Node.js console tells me that "google is not defined". Any idea of the problem and solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to access Google Feed API using Node.js, you should try the google-feed-api module as explained here:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/google-feed-api

Hope it helps!

Edit:

I tried this with your URL and worked fine:

```
var gfeed = require('google-feed-api');
var feed = new gfeed.Feed('http://rss.lemonde.fr/c/205/f/3050/index.rss');
feed.listItems(function(items){
    console.log(items);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `google` is literally not defined. I don't know very much about that module, but I think that instead of using the `google` var you should use `client` , because that's what the `execute` function returns.
So the code would be:

```
// parts omitted
var googleapis = require('googleapis');
// parts omitted
googleapis.discover('feeds').execute(function(err, client) {
var feed = new client.feeds.Feed('http://rss.lemonde.fr/c/205/f/3050/index.rss');
});
// parts omitted
```

Comment: Thanks. What's exactly the difference with my code?

Comment: Line 5:  
var feed = new client.feeds.Feed('http://rss.lemonde.fr/c/205/f/3050/index.rss');  
Instead of google,client.