# Subscribe to RSS feed with Google Feed API and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, rss, google-feed-api

From a Node.js server, I connected to Google Feed API (with https://stackoverflow.com/a/22821516/3303704).
But it seems to load the whole RSS feed every time I use it. Since I want to follow a lot of RSS feeds, it is not going to be scalable. How can I susbcribe to the RSS feeds, that is having pushed to my server only the new items of the RSS feeds, as they are published?
The solution described here (http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feed-api-now-with-instant.html) does not seem to work...

If it is useful, what I then do with the items of the RSS feeds is: (1) select only the links to articles with >1500 words (for that I use Cheerio) and (2) save these links to a database (MongoDB, connected to server with Mongoose).

Comment: I'd suggest posting some code, or else this question will probably be closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid the Google Feeds API may not be the best candidate here as it's mostly a 'client side' API which would allow you to embed RSS feed's content on an HTML page.
If used from a backend, you'll probably have to poll them which will be cumbersome (and may conflict with Google's terms of usage).

You may want to check [Superfeedr](http://superfeedr.com/) for this. We do provide a [Node.js wrapper](https://github.com/superfeedr/superfeedr-node) that does what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be useful. I have some problems to install the module, though, but that's a new question...